# How do I effectively write a common json patch to patch a json file in Go?

Tags: json, go, patch

I have a json n file like this

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "groups": [
       {
         "name": "first",
         "version": "v1"
       },
       {
         "name": "second",
         "version": "v2"
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I want to change the version of all the groups above.

I saw there's this https://jsonpatch.com/ RFC which helps in patching. But the path is very limited in this approach. I cannot select all versions of the groups and replace them in bulk. Something like this is not possible

```
{ 
  "op": "replace",
  "path": "metadata.groups[*].version"
  "value": "v2"
}
```

Now the suggestion might be to write one patch for one group. That will not suffice because I am generating this patch object for many json files. Each json file can have different number of "groups".

Is there a common json patch object that I can build to do these kinds of changes on the target json? Preferably this should be doable in Go language.

Comment: You can try [this](https://github.com/evanphx/json-patch)

Comment: @Rajesh That won't cut it. I can still not have a common patch object to change the source json.

Comment: If you see this -> https://jsonpath.com/, you will see there's a way to get all paths from a wildcard json expression. This is implemented in NodeJS. Is there something similar for Go?